# Frida - hooking a function inside a function

Tags: javascript, android, mobile, reverse-engineering, frida

I'm running Frida via python script on an Android device in order to change the functionality of an application.
I'm trying to hook a function which is inside another function, but I cannot find the way in order to do that.
I'm giving here the part of the relevant code that I'm trying to hook:

```
public class ClockInActivity extends Activity {
...

  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
  }

  public void btnClockIn(View view) {
    ...
    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Integer>() {
        public java.lang.Integer doInBackground(java.lang.Void... r14) {
        ...
        }

        public void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
        ...
        }
    } 
  }
}
```

(Where is "..." it's a code that not relevant).

I want to reach the "onPostExecute" method which it's inside btnClockIn.

My python code right now is like this:

```
import frida, sys

jscript = """
Java.perform(function() {
console.log("Injection");
    var change = Java.use('MyApplicationName.ClockInActivity');
    
    change.btnClockIn.implementation = function()
    {   
        console.log("check");
     }
   });
  """

 process = frida.get_usb_device(1).attach("MyApplicationName")
 script1 = process.create_script(jscript)
 script1.load()

 sys.stdin.read()
```

The check is working well. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Try hooking the AsyncClass like Java.use("android.os.AsyncTask").doInBackground.implementation

Answer (score 1):

The method `onPostExecute` does not belong to the class `MyApplicationName.ClockInActivity` but to an anonymous inner class. Anonymous inner classes don't have an own name, instead they just have a number appended to the class the reside in:

The first anonymous inner class in `ClockInActivity` therefore has the name `MyApplicationName.ClockInActivity$1`, for the second anonymous inner class it would be `MyApplicationName.ClockInActivity$2` and so on.

If you want to get thee exact name of an anonymous inner class decompile the APK file using the latest unstable version of Jadx. It will show you in comments the exact name of the anonymous inner class (you need the latest unstable because this feature was added after the latest release 1.1.0).

Assuming that the AsyncTask you want to hook is the first anonymous inner class you have to use the following code:

```
    var change = Java.use('MyApplicationName.ClockInActivity$1');
    
    change.onPostExecute.implementation = function()
    {   
        console.log("check");
     }
   });
```